# Fancybox is not loading

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

Fancybox is not working for me but I can't figure it out. I think I did everything as required.
Code Stuff:

```
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/ase/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/ase/js/transition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/ase/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/ase/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/wp-content/themes/ase/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    </script>
```

later:

```
<a href="/wp-content/gallery/uber-uns/armatur-1.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox">/wp-content/gallery/uber-uns/armatur-1.png</a>


<a href="/wp-content/gallery/uber-uns/armatur-2.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox">/wp-content/gallery/uber-uns/armatur-2.png</a>


<a href="/wp-content/gallery/uber-uns/armatur-3.png" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox">/wp-content/gallery/uber-uns/armatur-3.png</a>
```

The Links are absolute because they are created by WordPress.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: try wrapping your `$('.fancybox').fancybox();` inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: can we see the whole html? perhaps, it may be because you're executing the script before the a tags. try moving the $('.fancybox').fancybox() script below the definition for the a tags

Answer (score 1):

what if you try :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, but if I do this, I am not redirected to the image. It happens nothing visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug with Firefox or dev tools in Safari or IE to look at the javascript errors you're getting.

And with Wordpress, you need to correctly enqueue scripts rather than simply link them in header.php, esp. for the jQuery libraries and other scripts that depend on jQuery. Your theme may already be loading the main jQuery library.

And if transition.js is dependent on jQuery - which is probably is - load it in functions.php

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

As an example from that doc, this goes in functions.php of your theme:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/transition.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```